# ddrescue only rescued half the drive, how do I salvage the rest?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery, ddrescue

I have a USB hard drive that appears to have failed. Now I'm trying to transfer as much data as possible to a fresh drive with `ddrescue -n -f -v /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc2 recovery.log`. I ran into the error message `Input file disappeared: no such file or directory` a few times, with things like this in `dmesg`:

```
[13140.221752] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb1, logical block 481912624, async page read
[13185.036766] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Timeout while waiting for setup device command
[13185.248736] usb 3-3: device not accepting address 27, error -62
[13185.256853] usb usb3-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

Physically detaching and attaching it again would work for a while, but now it seems stuck at 49%. Every time I start the process again, the drive disappears after a short while with no progress.

Can I either tell ddrescue to skip the problematic region or can I somehow mount the incomplete file system on the new drive to see what I've got so far? I'm hesitant to mount the new drive even in readonly and wanted to make sure that it is safe to do so first.

Comment: Did you read [ddrescue manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html)?

Comment: Yes I read the manual

Comment: Well, it has a direct answer to your question. It has tons of suggestions how to influence where it starts reading disk an in which order it does that.

Answer (score 1):

The disk is probably a SATA disk with a USB bridge.

Open the enclosure, remove the USB-SATA bridge, and connect it to a SATA controller and repeat your attempt.